# Prioritized solution of a linear system subject to inequality constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, polytopes, quadratic-programming

Consider the following linear system 
\begin{equation}
y = A_1 x_1 + A_2 x_2 
\end{equation}
subject to the linear constrains
\begin{equation}
C_1 x_1 + C_2 x_2 \leq d 
\end{equation}

I am looking for a solution for the above linear system that gives more priority to the coordinates corresponding to $x_1$ compared to those of $x_2$. This is what I precisely mean by priority

1. If $x_1$ alone can geenerated the given $y$ while $x_2$ is kept at its minimum feasible value.
2. If there are infinite number of solutions for $x_1$ in step 1 then we take the minimum norm solution.
3. If $x_1$ alone cannot generate $y$ then we allow $x_2$ to participate in generating $y$ with the optimal $x_1$ obtained in step 1 and 2.
4. If there are infinite solutions for $x_2$, then we take the minimum norm solution.

How to formuate the above described problem as an optimization problem for instance QP?

PS. I am not interested in weighted solutions for the sake of priority. Priority is required to be strict.

I would try to describe my problem in another way. But maximizing $x_1$ probably will not be the best solution. I need $x_1$ to minimize $(y-A_1 x_1)^T(y-A_1 x_1)$. If we can find $x_1$ that allows this cost to be zero, then there is no need for $x_2$ at all and it will be set to zero of couse if $0 \in {Cx \leq d}$ (let's take it as an assumption for the moment). Probably, there may a finite number of solutions for $x_1$ that let the cost $(y-A_1 x_1)^T(y-A_1 x_1)$ to be zero. In this case, I would seek the solution that minimises $x_1^Tx_1$. If there is a residual from the above problem then we let $x_2$ to minimize this residual i.e. minimise $(y-A_1 x_1^* - A_2 x_2 )^T(y-A_1 x_1^* - A_2 x_2)$ subject to $ C_2 x_2 \leq d-C_1 x_1^*$

Comment: If you want priority on $x_1$, set $x_1$ to $d/C1$ and $x_2$ to $0$. (This is equivalent to adding weights $1$ and $0$ to $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $y$)

Comment: Setting $x_1 = d/C_1$ and $x_2 = 0$ is not necessairly a solution to $y = A_1 x_1 + A_2 x_2$ but indeed satisfies inequality constraints. I am looking for the general case where $A_1$ and $A_2$ and $C_1$ and $C_2$ are general matrices of appropriate dimensions.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your problem. Proposed something else in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem, but I think what you want is to solve
$$
\max_{x_1,x_2}\;x_1
$$
subject to
\begin{cases}
A_1x_1+A_2x_2=y\\
C_1x_1+C_2x_2\le d
\end{cases}

This is straightforward with the simplex algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I probably did not describe my problem very well in proper math terms. I am not a math guy. I would try to describe may problem in another way.

Comment: Description of the problem already updated

Comment: Just to come back to your answer. The maximization of $x_1$ would be undesirable in my problem (robotics problem).

Comment: I'm very confused as to what you want :) Solving the above problem will achieve your point $1$ ("If $x_1$ alone can generate the given $y$
 while $x_2$  is kept at its minimum feasible value"). $x_1$ will be maximized, but will still always respect the two other constraints. If you have more robotics related constraints, you need to explicit them so we can take them into account.